# Changing out driver on sequential switchback DRL LED strip

Tags: automotive, led-strip, led-driver

I recently purchased [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2x-Switchback-Flowing-Car-Truck-LED-Strip-Light-Sequential-Turn-Signal-Headlight/142788934396?rt=nc&_trkparms=aid%3D555018%26algo%3DPL.SIM%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D50543%26meid%3D92ca375cfee1470a94068f4ddc418c1c%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D4%26rkt%3D12%26sd%3D272931243239%26itm%3D142788934396&_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851) sequential DRL LED kit and tested it on the turn signal in my car. Unfortunately the frequencies don't line up so I was going to try to replace the driver so that I can still use the kit.

The chip on the LED boards is an [INK1003 IC Driver](http://www.ledlightmake.com/ledlightmake_serv/DataSheet%20Of%20INK1003-%20Ledlightmake.pdf)

I see the front of the controller says "Output: CV10.4v". Does that mean the existing driver is a constant voltage driver? And I don't need to worry about constant current?

Unfortunately the controller has been filled with some sort of rubber so I can't actually see the components that are in there. Here are some photos of the existing controller: [image] [image]

And my second question is: do I have enough information to know how to trigger the amber sequential lights? Or would I need to see the inside of the driver to know how to do that?

Closeup of the lights here:[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: As it says on the label, it's a constant voltage Power Supply, not a controller.  What is the chip on the LED board?

Comment: I updated the question with better terminology. I got confused about the "/MAX1.5A" part of the output. I guess that just means that driver won't output more than 1.5A? Each segment of the strip has a 8 pin chip that says `INK1003 121724`. I can't actually see any chips within the existing driver because it's been covered. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I added the datasheet.  Somewhere there is a micro-controller that is sending data to these INK RGB LED drivers.  These INK drivers  have a data in (DI pin 6) and data out (DO pin 5).  All these chips are daisy chained. The controller will be connected to pin 6 of the first INK chip in the chain.

Comment: Are you saying the existing micro-controller is in the same housing as the power supply? And that controller is outputting to the black/red/yellow wires to the DI pin of the first chip?

Comment: No, it is only a power supply.  The INK chips must be programmed before they will light up so there must be a micro-controller to do the programming.  To find the micro-controller you follow the PCB track from pin 6 back to the INK chip's pin 5 (DO) or the micro-controller.  One of the INK chips's pin 6 (DI) is fed from the micro-controller the rest are fed from the subsequent chip's DO in the serial data chain.

Comment: From what I can tell both pin 5 and 6 are both connected to components with `510` on them. Pin 6 is labeled `R1` on the board and pin 5 is labeled `R0`. Those two components are directly beside each other on the pcb but I can't tell if they are connected. Each segment appears to be identical though - even the first one. One other question: if the power supply is just a power supply why does it have black, red, and yellow wires. The yellow wire on the input of the power supply triggers the sequential amber effect. Thanks again very much for the help.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking at Rout and Gout pins 1 and 2.  Wrong corner of the chip.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78568/discussion-between-lop-luke-and-misunderstood).